# Tooltip in Javascript with if else condition

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a tooltip in javascript which is defined something like this:

```
   tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:f} </b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
```

I am interested in modifying the pointFormat field of tooltip.

It has one cell which is defined something like this:

```
point.y:f
```

I looked at the associated javascript file where it was defined and found out that 'f' is a variable.

I wanted to apply "if else" condition on that variable.
like

```
if(f==-1)
{
    display: 'NA';//display NA in that cell
}
else
    display: f;
```

Is it possible to do this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: which tooltip library are you using?

Comment: I am using highcharts.js

Comment: Don't really know your library, but as f is a variable of y where y is a variable of point, I'd access it like that `myvar = point.y.f`

Comment: @jPO it is not getting required result from that either. Any other method? Can you have a look at the library once if its possible? http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js

Comment: can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: Here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/q5eP3/

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to this fiddle below . I hope it will solve your problem. You can use conditional point but it needs to be defined as a formatter as below

```
tooltip:{
                formatter:function(){

                    if(this.point.y == 0)
                        return 'ON'
                    else
                        return 'OFF'

                }
            },
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5eP3/)

Comment: The hover window is gone if I add this in my code. I just want to display "NA" if my "f" value is "-1" and height of bar should be zero.